# Swing: mouse event on JTree or other components becomes skipped sometimes

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jpopup

I need to show popup-menu on my JTree, and I added mouse listener just like that:

```
  tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me)){
           //.. some code to show popup menu
        }
     }
  });
```

But sometimes this event is just skipped: I clicked, but `mouseClicked()` is not called. The same happens with `JTabbedPane`: i do right click on some tab, and **sometimes `mouseClicked()` is not called, but tab becomes actually switched**.

**UPD**: this happens in 10% of clicks, approximately. Too often to ignore it.

By the way, I can add `ChangeListener` on such `JTabpedPane`, and this event is never skipped, but i need to handle mouse too, and I have absolutely no idea what can be wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that in 10% of clicks you are not actually **clicking** but **starting and finishing a drag**. That is why mouseClicked event doesn't work.

Try listening mousePressed or mouseReleased MouseAdapter's event (depends on what behavior you want) instead of mouseClicked event.

Comment: It seems like your guess is quite right, thank you very much! I even thought that it is some kind of swing bug, or something.